# how to make a modal with asp mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

I have a question , I have in my view a form, this form contains a list , this list contains four attributes , vendor , application , product and value , these 4 we display only two ( as seen in the code) would like to display in a modal product and the value of the order , the list is displayed in the same position already has such data , how do I display that data through an action of my button that has the action " getFornecedor " ( this action has not yet been implemented , I do not know if it is necessary because the elements are in the same position in the list )

View

```
@model Test.Models.Order

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Teste</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap.css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <style>
        th {
            height: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
        <div id="divbody">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    </nav>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Cab", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div class="table-responsive" id="table">
                    <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead style="position:static">
                            <tr>
                                <th style="font-size:10px">SELECT</th>
                                <th style="font-size:10px">CONTACT</th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th style="font-size:10px">SUPPLY</th>
                                <th style="font-size:10px">ORDER</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.listOrder.Count(); i++)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" height="2px">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.listOrder[i].isEdit, new { @onclick = "habilit(" + i + ")", @id = "c" + i })</td>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("getFornecedor", "MyController")" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("sendEmail", "MyController")" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td height="2px"> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.listOrder[i].supply, new { @readonly = "readonly", @size = "18px", @class = "form-controlSupply" }) </td>
                                <td height="2px"> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.listOrder[i].order, new { @readonly = "readonly", @size = "75px", @class = "form-controlOrder" }) </td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </table>
                </div>
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Salve" id="btn" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" />
            }
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

MVC doesn`t have modal on fly .. (like control in web forms for example) i suggest you to use third party library , may be something like jquery UI .. You can see example here : https://jqueryui.com/dialog/
You just need client side event to show modal dialog. In that container you can put any data that you want.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to pick up the value of my list ?